# How to plot several layers using GeoPandas

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas

I am trying to use geopandas to plot some info over a map. The first thing that I do is to upload a shape file of New York City:

```
nyc_boroughBoundaries = geopandas.read_file ("nybb_19b2")
```

This is returning a geodataframe:

```
type (nyc_boroughBoundaries)

geopandas.geodataframe.GeoDataFrame
```

And has a geometry column:

```
geometry

(POLYGON ((1012821.805786133 229228.2645874023...
(POLYGON ((970217.0223999023 145643.3322143555...
(POLYGON ((1029606.076599121 156073.8142089844...
```

I am repeating the same process to load some information about new constructions in NYC

```
geo_df_NB_2018["Coordinates"]

POINT (40.62722 -73.969634)
POINT (40.764575 -73.955421)
POINT (40.525584 -74.166414)
POINT (40.742845 -73.89083100000001)
POINT (40.679859 -73.93992
```

Then I am trying to plot both geodataframes in one single map doing the following:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots (figsize = (15,15))
geo_df_NB_2018.plot(ax = ax, alpha = 0.7, color = "pink")
nyc_boroughBoundaries.plot(ax = ax)
```

However, they are being displayed in different parts of the figure.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: your code seems right but you should switch the line and plot the points on the top of the polygons. meanwhile, it seems as you've might convert your point coordinates wrongly and try to switch lon and lat.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you mean this:

    fig, ax = plt.subplots (figsize = (15,15))
    nyc_boroughBoundaries.plot(ax = ax, alpha = 0.7, color = "pink")
    geo_df_NB_2018.plot(ax = ax)

If so, I am still getting the same issue

Comment: I am just not quite sure what you mean by switching the line and plot the points on the top of the polygons

Comment: where you got those points from? did you convert them yourself? If so, switch the lon and lat and try again?

Comment: @steve thanks! it is working now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have different projections. They need to be the same to be plotted together. Look at your coordinates, they are clearly different. Moreover, as @steven pointed out, you have switched latitude and longitude. Fix that first and then reproject:

```
# convert CRS to the same as nyc_boroughBoundaries has
geo_df_NB_2018 = geo_df_NB_2018.to_crs(nyc_boroughBoundaries.crs)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 15))
geo_df_NB_2018.plot(ax=ax, alpha=0.7, color="pink")
nyc_boroughBoundaries.plot(ax=ax)
```

Answer (score 3):

This is also possible, since `.plot` is returning an axis object:

```
import geopandas as gpd

file1 = r"C:\GIS\data\data1.gpkg"
file2 = r"C:\GIS\data\data2.gpkg"
admin = gpd.read_file(file1, layer="admin")
set_asides = gpd.read_file(file2, layer="protected_areas")

ax = admin.plot(color="palegreen", edgecolor="green", figsize=(20, 10))
set_asides.plot(ax=ax, color="red")
```

[image]